# How do you set a variable number of regex expressions?

Tags: python, regex

Currently I have `out = re.sub(r'[0-9][0-9][0-9]', '', input)`. I would like to have a variable number of `[0-9]`'s.

So far I have;

```
string = ''
for i in xrange(numlen):
    string = string + '[0-9]'

string = 'r' + string
out = re.sub(string, '', input)
```

This doesn't work, and I've tried using `re.compile`, but haven't had any luck. Is there a better way of doing this? Or am I just missing something trivial?

Comment: Adding `r` to the front of the string doesn't make it a raw string. `r'foo'` and `'rfoo'` are entirely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify repetition using `{}`, for example 3 digits would be

```
[0-9]{3}
```

So you can do something like

```
reps = 5 # or whatever value you'd like
out = re.sub('[0-9]{{{}}}'.format(reps), '', input)
```

Or if you don't know how many digits there will be

```
out = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', input)
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for using a variable inside `{}` rather than an integer literal (or a pair of comma-separated integers)? I'm unaware of that working.

Comment: @chepner You are correct, I cannot directly use a variable in the pattern like that. Sebastian's suggestion will do the trick in this case.

Comment: Removed my comment because I messed up the details - but what you inserted, was what I meant :p

Comment: Great answer, but in the case of `"[0-9]"`, `r"\d"` would work also.

Answer (score 1):

Use quantified `+` which would match one or more occurence of digits

```
out = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', input)
```

See how the regex matches http://regex101.com/r/cE6yS6/1

For example

```
>>> import re
>>> word="hello 123"
>>> out = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', word)
>>> word
'hello 123'
>>> out
'hello '
```